# How to remove all notifications from notification bar in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, dart, flutter

I want to remove all cancelable notifications from status bar in Flutter. I know how to remove my app notifications I have seen this post before, but I want to remove other apps notifications.

Comment: Could you do this?

Comment: @Rudy_TM no I could not do this!

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is an available package that you can use.

> [clear_all_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/clear_all_notifications)
>
> A Flutter plugin for clearing all Android and iOS active notifications
>
> To clear all active notifications call
>
> ```
> await ClearAllNotifications.clear();
> ```

You can check the example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/clear_all_notifications/example).